# How to get second word in url php

Tags: php, url, uri

For example I have url: stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. I want to get a string between first and second slash. It should be word `questions` from it. How can I do it?

Comment: Try [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a folder in your website and put there a dcument in, you should navigate to "web.site/foldername/document" to access it.

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question.

Comment: Yeah me too but its a try.

Comment: @Zniets I think I have to separate url with `/` and get second word

Comment: what is your goal behind this?